# Code for checking the symmetry of a binary tree doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree, symmetry

> Given the root of a binary tree, check whether it is a mirror of itself (i.e., symmetric around its center).

It's easy to find a solution that works, but I was wondering why my solution doesn't work.
The way I tried doing this is the following: first reflect the original tree about the vertical axis passing through the root, and then compare the reflected tree with the original tree. The reflected tree is equal to the original tree iff the original tree is symmetric.

My code is below. It breaks, for example for the input `root = [1,2,2,null,3,null,3]` -- the output is True instead of False. But I don't see why this is happening; the two internal functions work as intended I believe.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right

class Solution:
    def isSymmetric(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
        def invertTree(root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> Optional[TreeNode]:
            if root is None:
                return None
            root.left, root.right = invertTree(root.right), invertTree(root.left)

            return root

        def isSameTree(p: Optional[TreeNode], q: Optional[TreeNode]) -> bool:
            if p is None and q is None:
                return True
            elif p is not None and q is None:
                return False
            elif p is None and q is not None:
                return False
            elif p.val != q.val: 
                return False

            return isSameTree(p.left, q.left) and isSameTree(p.right, q.right)

        inverted_root = invertTree(root)

        return isSameTree(root, inverted_root)
```

Comment: `invertTree()` modifies the tree in place, it doesn't create a new tree. So of course they're the same.

Comment: Consider implementing `__copy__(self)` in your `TreeNode` class (so that it creates a _deep_ copy) and then using `inverted_root = invertTree(root.copy())`. the deepcopy function from the copy library could also help. Note that copying could be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix would be:

```
root_copy = copy.deepcopy(root)
inverted_root = invertTree(root)
return isSameTree(root_copy, inverted_root)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `invertTree` function does not create a new tree, but mutates the given tree. There is only one `root`, but you just got a new reference to it with `inverted_root`. Comparing `root` with `inverted_root` is comparing the (mutated) tree with itself and will always return `True`.

You can still use the idea of the *inplace* mutation of the tree, but apply it only on the right subtree, and then check whether the (non modified) left subtree is the same as the (mutated) right subtree.

To do that, replace these statements:

```
        inverted_root = invertTree(root)
        return isSameTree(root, inverted_root)
```

with:

```
        inverted_right = invertTree(root.right)
        return isSameTree(root.left, inverted_right)
```

NB: it is given in the code challenge that the tree has at least one node, so `root` will not be `None`.